# Generate WFS-T insert and delete requests using wfs-t openlayers3

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I am trying to insert feature like point, line, etc on "india_ds" wfs layer map using wfs-t but not able to make successful POST request using openlayers3. I have post my script and error. I have linked my "india_ds" layer with PostGIS. Also, do I have to make any changes from my geoserver account and postGIS? I am new to openlayers and geoserver. Please help.

```
 <script>

      var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

      var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
          featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite',
          featureType: 'india_ds1',
          srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
      });



      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&' +
              'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:india_ds1&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });



      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
      });

      var interaction;

var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});

var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FF2828'
        })
    })
});

var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: vector.getSource()
});

      var view =  new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        interactions: [
            interactionSelectPointerMove,
            new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.DragPan()
        ],
        layers: [vector],
        view: view
      });

      var dirty = {};
var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
    var node;
    switch (mode) {
        case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
            break;
    }
    var xs = new XMLSerializer();
    var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
    var geo = f.getGeometry();
    var geometry = geo.getCoordinates();

var postData = '<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"\
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\
  xmlns:cite="http://www.openplans.org/cite"\
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"\
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/cite http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=cite:india_ds1">\
  <wfs:Insert>\
    <cite:india_ds1>\
      <cite:geom>\
        <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">\
          <gml:lineStringMember>\
            <gml:LineString>\
             <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:3857">\
              <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">\
'+geometry+'\
              </gml:coordinates>\
               </gml:LineString>\
            </gml:LineString>\
          </gml:lineStringMember>\
        </gml:MultiLineString>\
      </cite:geom>\
      <cite:TYPE>alley</cite:TYPE>\
    </cite:india_ds1>\
  </wfs:Insert>\
</wfs:Transaction>';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/ows',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: postData,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(" point features were posted to server");
        console.log(response);
        }
    }).done();

};

$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('btn-active');
    map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear();
    map.removeInteraction(interactionSelect);

    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {

        case 'btnEdit':
            map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: interactionSelect.getFeatures()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            map.addInteraction(interactionSnap);
            dirty = {};
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                e.element.on('change', function (e) {
                    dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                });
            });
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('remove', function (e) {
                var f = e.element;
                if (dirty[f.getId()]) {
                    delete dirty[f.getId()];
                    var featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                    delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                    var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                    clone.setId(f.getId());
                    transactWFS('update', clone);
                }
            });
            break;

        case 'btnPoint':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Point',
                source: vector.getSource(),
                geometryName:'geom'
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
              var feature = e.feature;
              feature.set('geom', feature.getGeometry());
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnLine':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'LineString',
                source: vector.getSource(),
                    geometryName:'geom'
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
              var feature = e.feature;
              feature.set('geom', feature.getGeometry());
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnArea':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'MultiPolygon',
                source: vector.getSource(),
                geometryName:'geom'
            });
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {

              var feature = e.feature;
              feature.set('geom', feature.getGeometry());
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
                });

            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        case 'btnDelete':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
            interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                transactWFS('delete', e.target.item(0));
                interactionSelectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                interaction.getFeatures().clear();
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});

    </script>
```

error :- 
      `<ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for coordinates: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to usecom.vividsolutions.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequenceFactory@2cb1c829 to produce CoordinateSequence with dimension 6
Parsing failed for coordinates: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to usecom.vividsolutions.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequenceFactory@2cb1c829 to produce CoordinateSequence with dimension 6
Unable to usecom.vividsolutions.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequenceFactory@2cb1c829 to produce CoordinateSequence with dimension 6
</ServiceException>`

Comment: Have you tried to paste the request in GeoServer demo section? there is an option to check if whether the wfst is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like GeoServer can't understand the coordinates you have sent, it seems to think you are using 6 dimensional space.

I suspect that this line is the issue:

```
<gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">\
 '+geometry+'\
</gml:coordinates>
```

Since your geometry is just an array of coordinates it is unlikely to end up as valid GML. You need to provide a list of coordinates separated by `,` (that's what `cs=","` means) and spaces separating the points (`ts=" "`), so something like:

```
<gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
   x1,y2 x2,y2 x3,y3 ...
</gml:coordinates>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer but I see at least 2 issues

- your code contains a function with a wrong signature.  `writeTransaction` uses `writeTransaction(inserts, updates, deletes, options)` whereas your code don't do thing this way as the last argument is an instance of `ol.format.GML` instead of an object with options. See [the API doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.WFS.html#writeTransaction)
- you don't need to use `postData` (normally, you should just drop it) but instead `payload`. `data: postData,` should be `data: payload,`